# How to socialize unneutered female and male rabbit, before or after neutering?

Tags: rabbits, socializing, neutering

**Situation:**

We own an unneutered female rabbit, since one week she is alone because her partner died. The search for a new partner is difficult, because we want an adult neutered rabbit-man for her, dwarf, no teddy fur and no lop ears.
We have found one male rabbit, but he is unneutered.
(Searched in animal shelters and small ad)

**Aim:**

We want to exclude the cause, that they absolute dislike each other, before we neuter the male. But we do not want the female to become pregnant.

**Question(s)**

Is there the chance to do so?

Can neutering change something, so it works before, but not after it?

How big is the risk, they see and at once start to mate?

**Background**

The actual owner of the male would take him back, if the socializing do not work well. I assume neutering is not part of this. Additional I want to spare the male the neutering, if we can not keep him with our female.

Comment: Partial update: At the pickup we had sat them together to exclude they immediate starts fighting. They both were very peaceful and after 30 seconds he starts to climb on her back... :D we at once separated them before there were near contact. Now he is neutered and they wait for the 4 weeks to go by until they can live together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not put the female and male together, see [this answer for more detail](https://pets.stackexchange.com/a/6586/13) when the male mounts the female she will release eggs, and get pregnant. The chance of this are very high, near 100%

There are hormone changes after the surgery, it is best to wait 30 days after the surgery before introducing the rabbits to each other.

The hormone change with spay/neuter can be significant, that any meetings prior to the surgery do not provide a good gauge, for future meeting.

On occasion, brother and sister rabbits who have always lived together will start fighting and need to be separated permanently after spay/neuter.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. How would you solve the problem?

Comment: @Allerleirauh I would spay and neuter them both, wait 30 days then introduce them. This is can be challenging, so after I spayed her, I would go to a shelter or rescue for a rabbit that was already spayed.

Comment: Surprisingly for me, luckily for the rabbits, there were only 4 male in the rescue/shelters in our region. two with teddy fur, one baby and one with lop ears (because rain and flies fur and ears better have to been "natural" for outdoor rabbits)

Comment: Now the plan is like this: We divide the enclosure into two (it is designed this way, to have chance to separate ill rabbit). Until they are neutered and the waiting time is ending one rabbit lives in each part. And we badly hope they will socialize after all... There is nothing without any risk